# Check if an object is of this class type in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, casting

I want to override `equals` function of a class. How can I check if the `other` object is of the same class as `this`?

Have tried the following, but it does not work

```
data class Alert(
    //properties
) {
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        return other is this.javeclass //&& compare property values
    }
}
```

Comment: IntelliJ does a pretty good job of generating these for you. Right click, then click Generate. Also, if you use a data class, you don't need to write explicit `equals` and `hashCode` implementatIons at all.

Comment: Wow! I did not know about the `Generate` command. Thanks a lot! When `equals` is not overridden, IntelliJ suggests to use `==` instead of `equals`. Does it mean that in the former case it will compare the properties as well, not just the class references? Although this solves my usecase in full, I would still like to know if it is possible to cast the other object to `this` class without hardcoding the class name.

Comment: `==` in Kotlin is almost the same as `equals`, except it also does some additional null checks. Why don't you want to hardcode the class name? How would casting be any useful if you only know the target type at runtime?

Comment: The code snippet generated by IntelliJ contains `if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false; other as Alert`. So I just wander why cann't we write `other is javaClass` or `other as javaClass`? Is this a bug or something?

Comment: The comparison is (more explicitly) ``if (this.javaClass != other?.javaClass)`` - ``javaClass`` is a property that gets its Java class representation, i.e ``this.javaClass`` returns ``Class<Alert>``. That's a special type of object that represents the *Alert* class, and allows you to access all its properties, construct instances etc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html So the class of the object returned by ``.javaClass`` is a *Class*, **not** an *Alert*, so ``is`` will fail because they're different types.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *other::class == this::class* for the class type comparison and then – since you comment in your code: *// && compare property values* – you could use reflection to compare the properties (note that this will compare scalar properties, but not object properties unless they themselves implement comparison for all properties):

```
import kotlin.reflect.full.declaredMemberProperties

data class Alert(
  val prop1: String = "",
  val prop2: Int = 0
) {

  override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
    return other != null &&
           other::class == this::class &&
           this::class.declaredMemberProperties.none {
             it.call(this) != it.call(other)
           }
  }

  override fun hashCode(): Int {
    return javaClass.hashCode()
  }

}

println(Alert("abc", 123) == Alert("abc", 123))      // true
println(Alert("abc", 123) == Alert("abcdef", 123))   // false
println(Alert("abc", 123) == Alert("abc", 123456))   // false
```